# Oracle ODP Naming Convention Confusion

Tags: oracle

I've got some .Net software that's using a DLL of Oracle is ODP.Net that is tagged as version 2.111.6.20.  What database release does that map to?  Is there any pattern to how they name these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the ODP FAQ:](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/faq.html#versioning)

> Q: In ODP.NET 10.2.0.2 and higher, why
>   does the same ODP.NET provider have
>   two different version numbers?
>
> A: For ODP.NET 10.2.0.2 and higher,
>   the same ODP.NET binaries have two
>   different version numbers when viewed
>   from either .NET products (e.g. Visual
>   Studio 2005 would see version
>   2.102.2.20) or when viewed from Oracle products (e.g. Oracle Universall
>   Installer would see version
>   10.2.0.2.20). Prior to ODP.NET 10.2.0.2, the latter versioning was employed exclusively. The use [of] the
>   second versioning method was necessary
>   to properly support .NET policy files
>   for .NET Framework 1.x and 2.0.

Here is the [version scheme](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/InstallVersioningScheme.htm):

> For example, if the ODP.NET product
>   version number is 11.1.0.6.20, the
>   corresponding ODP.NET assembly
>   versions are:
>
> - .NET Framework 1.x version: 1.111.6.20
> - .NET Framework 2.0 version: 2.111.6.20

Your version therefore refers to Oracle 11.1.0.6, for the .NET 2.0 framework.